# Will all aldehydes and ketones give 2,4-DNP test?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I've recently gone through 2,4-DNP test for aldheydes and ketones on [Byjus](https://byjus.com/chemistry/2-4-dinitrophenylhydrazine/):

> An aqueous solution of 2,4-dinitrophenyl hydrazine (DNP) is known as Brady’s reagent. It reacts with carbonyl compounds (aldehydes and ketone) to give a colored precipitate.

From the above statement, I think only water-soluble aldehydes and ketones give the test, but my teacher said *all* aldehydes and ketones (carbohydrates excluded) give 2,4-DNP test.

Who is correct? My teacher or the website?

Comment: Glucose doesn't give 2,4-DNP test.

Comment: @NilayGhosh Yes, of course, but I actually wanted to ask about simple aldehydes and ketones.

Comment: 2,4-DNP test can be based on solvents other than water e.g. alcohols